Interpretation of these Letters?
What are different gematria interpretations of די (Dalet, Yud), 14? What is the depth of this combination in this order? Do I interpret them together or each individually and what is the depth, insight of די if it is the calendar date of a Jew's birthday?
Looking for insight that's beyond Pshat level, already knowing that Dalet can represent delet, dal, dilisoni or fullness, completion. And Yud represents Yid, Yad of H', his name, a heightened level of connection.
Sincerely thank you!

What's a birthday letter?

The date of one's Hebrew Birthday.

Are you asking if there is significance to the word formed by the day of the month of one's birthday? If yes please clarify, otherwise the question risks getting closed for lack of clarity.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

I don't know of any general system, but there's a saying in Chabad that ח"י אלול (the birthday of the Besh"t and the Baal HaTanya) brings "life" into Elul. I think there's a similar idea about ח"י אייר (Lag Baomer).

I would say that edit was - enough
